# Paypal payout PHP internal server error when creating new ProductionEnvironment object

Tags: php, paypal, payout

I'm trying to integrate [PaypalPayoutSDK](https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK) in my project. I've tried setting up the project like described in the instructions.

Here is what I have:

```
use PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\ProductionEnvironment;

// Creating an environment
$clientId = "myid";
$clientSecret = "mysecret";

$environment = new ProductionEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
```

And the folder structure is just:

```
-payment
  -myfile.php
  -PaypalPayoutsSDK
```

When I try to use  `new ProductionEnvironment()` I get an `500 Internal Server Error` I'm not very adept in PHP so I might not easily understand what's going on an how to fix it. For example I'm not using composer and I probably won't be able to unless it is absolutely necessary to get this to work. My project is purely PHP without anything added to it.

Here is the error message I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PaypalPayoutsSDK\Core\ProductionEnvironment' not found in /hermes/bosnaweb27a/b1507/dom.mynamestudios/myname/payment/payuser.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /hermes/bosnaweb27a/b1507/dom.mynamestudios/myname/payment/payuser.php on line 14
```

What could be the problem here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add things like:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To the top of your PHP file, you may get a more meaningful error message

Comment: Is your folder structure really `PaypalPayoutSDK` ? Because that would cause the error.

Comment: I was checking myself but it seems to be correct. The `payuser.php`-File is in the same folder as the `PaypalPayoutsSDK`-Folder .. I don't understand this?

Comment: I ended up using composer, there was no other option. This answer is correct since it helped me debug the problem. thanks!